# Two spinners next to eachother

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I have this problem when i put two spinners next to eachother. Here is the fragment of the layout xml:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/y"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/z"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF" >
    </ListView>
...
...
```

Here is the result:

[image: spinners]

I tried many different things. I've tried changing weights, gravity, changing the parent to RelativeLayout, but the result remained the same.

Please help!

EDIT:

Ok. I got it. Some redundancy, but it solves the problem. Kinda weird why this works and the "normal way" doesn't. Thanks for help everyone.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/y"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're having. Have you tried stripping everything but the two spinners next to each other - so just a single LinearLayout as root and two spinners? Also, do you have this issue in the preview in Eclipse as well as an actual device/emulator?

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a RelativeLayout, you could use `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/x"` and `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/x"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/y"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/x"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/x" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(I've left out the gravity definitions as they didn't seem to have an effect on the text in your spinner.)

Comment: Tried it. Using exactly the solution You've given yields the following: The first (leftmost) spinner fills the parent, pushing the other one off the screen. Additionally, switching to landscape causes an exception to occur. The exception says that android can't find "y" ("y" being the second (rightmost)) spinner.

Comment: I tried setting a fixed width for the first spinner. That worked. But now i don't have them filling exactly 50% of the parents width each. Also the exception i mentioned above is still present.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that exact problem, but I do see that you have both filling the parent with their width, which may conflict. I would replace that with `android:layout_width="0dip"` for all elements using weight to determine its size, that way they will actually be equal.

Comment: I just changed it. Did not help unfortunately. Let me add that this problem is also present in landscape.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I upvoted the question, hopefully it will get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution which work for me. I added  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" to spinner as below :

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/custSpinner"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/busSpinner"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

///// You can use spinner widht match parent or 0dp both works

```
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"  />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

althought i cant see anything wrong with this code , but i think you dont need to set gravity ,because wrap_content height will automatically put linearlayout at top and left and right is not the case because both spinners are of half width of screen .

so use :

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/y"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"  />
```

Comment: Nope. Same problem. Thanks though.